# Where have I gone wrong with my query?

Tags: php, mysql, join

I am quite a noob at PHP/MySQL an thus far have managed to get by, however, now I need to get information from two tables that are related.
I have done much research on what I need to do, but can't seem to figure out where I have gone wrong.

**QUESTION: How can I get the link from shortlinks table that is related to the shortlink in shortlink_analytics?**

I get the error: **Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given**

My tables are as follows:

**Shortlinks table**

id

shortlink

link

createdTime

createdBy

**shortlink_analytics table**

shortlink

referrer

hitTime

userIP

userAgent

The code I have tried so far is:

```
$linecount = 1;
//$mostPop is where I think I have gone wrong and this is where the warning refers to
$mostPop = "SELECT shortlink, COUNT(shortlink) FROM shortlink_analytics JOIN shortlinks ON shortlink_analytics.shortlink = shortlinks.shortlink GROUP BY shortlink ORDER BY COUNT(shortlink) DESC LIMIT 10";
            $loadPop = mysql_query($mostPop);
            echo '<table id="middleIndex">';
            echo '<tr><td class = "overFlow"><h2>Most Popular Shortlink</h2></td></tr>';
            echo '<tr>';
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($loadPop))
            {
                    echo '<td class = "overFlow">'.$row[1].' visits - <a href = "info.php?link='. $row['shortlink'] .'">hud.ac/' . $row['shortlink'] . '</a></td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                    $linecount++;
            }
            echo '<tr id="indexMiddle"><td id="hand" class = "overFlow"><a onclick="indexMostPopular()">View More</a></td></tr>';
                echo '</table>';
```

I beleive that I do not have a thorough enough understanding behind how to use **JOIN** or the parameters that are required to form a successful join.

Comment: Use `mysql_error` to find out what the SQL error was and work from there. Do note however that mysql_* functions are deprecated and should not really be used if at all possible. You should probably look into using mysqli or PDO.

Comment: Just a couple of notes. a) using the mysql_* family of functions is really strongly discouraged because they're not really maintained anymore and are deprecated in all but name.  YOu might want to switch to PDO or mysqli instead. b) The mixing of display logic (echoing HTML markup) and application logic (the database querying, etc) isn't recommended as it can lead to code that's very difficult to maintain.

Comment: cheers guys, I understand the mysql_* are now depreciated and I'm in the process of transfering my knowledge across to a newer convention, thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Before passing $loadPop to mysql_fetch_array, you've to make sure that $loadPop contains a valid value. mysql_query returns false in case of error.

Comment: Maybe practice your queries directly in MySQL work bench or other. Just makes it a bit easier if your a newb then you can transfer it to code ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have `shortlink` in both tables which will make ambiguous case. Try this **sql statement**:

```
$mostPop = "SELECT shortlink_analytics.shortlink AS short, 
COUNT(shortlink_analytics.shortlink) AS shortcount,
(SELECT link FROM shortlinks 
WHERE shortlinks.shortlink = shortlink_analytics.shortlink) AS shLink
FROM shortlink_analytics 
JOIN shortlinks ON shortlink_analytics.shortlink = shortlinks.shortlink 
GROUP BY shortlink_analytics.shortlink 
ORDER BY COUNT(shortlink_analytics.shortlink) DESC LIMIT 10";
```

Comment: How do I then get the output of the link to the screen inside my while loop, I tried using: ....'.$row['link'].'.. and ...'.$row['shortlinks.link'].'.. but when i tried it neither of them worked as they are undefined?

Comment: @SamStreet - I added **AS** to the query so  you can get it from the new name now like $row['short'] and $row['shortcount']

Comment: How do I get the **link** information from the other table and output it though, I can get the information such as short and shortcount, but it is the information from shortlinks that i also wish to display. (sorry for continually asking)

Comment: @SamStreet, no problem at all. but what data do you want from table shortlinks?

Comment: I wish to display the **link** from the shortlinks table in my html output, is this possible?

Comment: @SamStreet - I updated your query so you can get the link as shLink :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Run this query in mysql and if it is working add it in php script)

```
SELECT 
    shortlink_analytics.shortlink, COUNT(shortlink_analytics.shortlink)
FROM
    shortlink_analytics
INNER JOIN
    shortlinks ON shortlink_analytics.shortlink = shortlinks.shortlink
GROUP BY shortlink_analytics.shortlink
ORDER BY COUNT(shortlink_analytics.shortlink) DESC
LIMIT 10
```

And check `mysql_effected_rows()` function to check whether query will returns some row or not